# Excel doesn't show value as date although indicated with VT_DATE and using SystemTimeToVariantTime

Tags: excel, com

we are exporting to excel (office2010) via COM automation (C++).
Meaning we use SafeArrays, VARIANTs and the use the excel API like range->PutValue().

We have an issue on certain (not all) customer machines with exporting date values.
We normally indicate the value of the VARIANT as VT_DATE and fill in the date member.
Something like this:

```
VARIANT        vValue;
SYSTEMTIME     SystemTimeVal;
short          Year=2011;
short          Month=11;
short          Day=14;
short          Hour=0;
short          Minute=0;
short          Second=0;

SystemTimeVal.wYear   = (WORD)Year;
SystemTimeVal.wMonth  = (WORD)Month;
SystemTimeVal.wDay    = (WORD)Day;
SystemTimeVal.wHour   = (WORD)Hour;
SystemTimeVal.wMinute = (WORD)Minute;
SystemTimeVal.wSecond = (WORD)Second;

V_VT(&vValue) = VT_DATE;
SystemTimeToVariantTime(&SystemTimeVal, &(vValue.date));

// SafeArrayPutElement related code omitted here

pRange->PutValue(variantContainingSafeArray);

// ...
```

When opening the xls file, the value shown is as a number.
If you open Format dialog in Excel, it should "General".
In this case the number is 40861.
When letting Excel format it as Date, the correct date 14 november 2011 is shown.

On my pc and at other customers, Excel nicely formatted it as Date.
The case in which it happened is with a French customer, but colleages have used the same regional settings and language settings, and on their pc every thing goes fine... 
Also we have several other French customers and never got a complaint from them.

I suppose it must be some machine specific issue but have no clue...

Did somebody run into the same kind of issue?

Bart

Comment: Our customer deinstalled office2010 and installed office 2003 and it seems to work now.
When building our application we use excel9.olb which is not from office 2010.
Maybe there is some breaking change somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

it looks like installing SP1 for Office fixes the problem...